# Error running asp.net boilerplate application when adding Volo.Abp.EventBus.RabbitMQ package

Tags: rabbitmq, abp

I have an asp.net boilerplate application running the latest Volo.Abp framework.  I am trying to setup DistributedEventBus with RabbitMQ but adding the package causes an error. I have added the Volo.Abp.EventBus.RabbitMQ nuget package to my host and made no other changes at all.  Running the host app now causes the host to terminate with this error:

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Volo.Abp.Collections.ITypeList`1.TryAdd()'.
   at Volo.Abp.Validation.ValidationInterceptorRegistrar.RegisterIfNeeded(IOnServiceRegistredContext context)
   at Autofac.Builder.AbpRegistrationBuilderExtensions.InvokeRegistrationActions[TLimit,TActivatorData,TRegistrationStyle](IRegistrationBuilder`3 registrationBuilder, ServiceRegistrationActionList registrationActionList, Type serviceType, Type implementationType)
   at Autofac.Builder.AbpRegistrationBuilderExtensions.ConfigureAbpConventions[TLimit,TActivatorData,TRegistrationStyle](IRegistrationBuilder`3 registrationBuilder, IModuleContainer moduleContainer, ServiceRegistrationActionList registrationActionList)
   at Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AutofacRegistration.Register(ContainerBuilder builder, IServiceCollection services)
   at Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AutofacRegistration.Populate(ContainerBuilder builder, IServiceCollection services)
   at Volo.Abp.Autofac.AbpAutofacServiceProviderFactory.CreateBuilder(IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ServiceFactoryAdapter`1.CreateBuilder(IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
```

I have not added the Module as a dependency of my module or done any custom configuration of the event bus setup just added the nuget package.  It looks like `ValidationInterceptorRegistrar.RegisterIfNeeded` method is wrapping classes in dynamic proxies to do some validation and that it may be picking up some classes from the EventBus package and its causing an issue.  Has anyone seen this on ABP before?

These are the packages and version from ABP I am using

```
    <PackageReference Include="Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.MultiTenancy" Version="2.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Volo.Abp.Autofac" Version="2.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Theme.Basic" Version="2.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="2.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Serilog" Version="2.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Volo.Abp.Account.Web.IdentityServer" Version="2.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Volo.Abp.EventBus.RabbitMQ" Version="3.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Volo.Abp.Identity.Web" Version="2.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Volo.Abp.TenantManagement.Web" Version="2.9.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This was related to having different version of different Abp framework libraries when all framework references across all projects where updated to version 3.0.2 that resolved the issue.